# Chemistry behind adding methyl salicylate to iodine dissolved in petroleum jelly

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

We did a project at my school where we were asked to create a pain-relieving balm, inspired by Iodex. We first took 50gms of petroleum jelly and heated it in a water bath until it melted and became a clear liquid. Then we put 1.5 g of Iodine(the crystals) in it. We allowed it cool at room temperature and then added about 5 ml of methyl salicylate to get solidified Iodex, the paste with the minty smell.
I'm curious as to what goes behind the scenes and the reactions that are taking place here.

Comment: By "gms", you must mean "g" as SI symbol for the gram unit, right? Or? // Note also there is written a space between values and their units.

Comment: yes, I made the changes. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there are any chemical reactions taking place here. All you are doing is creating a mixture of a non-steroidal anti-inflammatory (methyl salicylate) and an antiseptic (iodine) in a spreadable medium (petroleum jelly)

Comment: @SolitarySolus if this answer helped, make sure to accept it by clicking the checkmark.